# Copy text without Input and button

Tags: html, css

How can I create an text to clipboard function?
I found on w3schools how to do it with an input but I don't know how to do it with just text (for example like Hypixel

Comment: Can you share the example you found?

Comment: "Copy text without Input and button" What action/event do you propose will activate the "copy to clipboard"?

Comment: you at least have to use something  a `span`  a `paragraph` a `h1` a `div`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an library to do this.
Just use  `document.execCommand("copy")`

```js
$("#txt").on("click", function (event) {
    var $temp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val($("#txt").html()).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="txt">Copy this text</div>
```